# Solving a large number of small linear systems

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I need to solve a large number of 3x3 symmetric, postive-definite systems with Python. So far, I did

```
res = numpy.zeros(n)
for k, obj in enumerate(data_array):
    # construct A, rhs, idx from obj
    res[idx] += numpy.linalg.solve(A, rhs)
```

This produces the correct result, however is also quite slow if `n` is large. (Well... Yeah.) Perhaps 3x3 isn't a problem size where calling `solve()` makes much sense.

Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In NumPy 1.8 and later, [`numpy.linalg.solve` actually broadcasts](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html). For `numpy.linalg.solve(a, b)`, if `b.ndim == a.ndim - 1`, it will perform a broadcasted matrix-vector solve; otherwise, it'll do a broadcasted matrix-matrix solve. (This decision criterion isn't documented; I had to look at the source.)

If you can efficiently construct a stack of `A`s and `rhs`s, you can call `solve` once and avoid a Python loop.

Comment: Just what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: The decision criterion is implied by `a : (..., M, M) array_like` and `b : {(..., M,), (..., M, K)}` in the documentation, albeit in somewhat cryptic form.

Comment: @pv.: Not really. For example, if you were going by those shapes, you'd expect `a.shape == (5, 5, 5, 5)` and `b.shape == (5, 5, 4)` to do matrix-matrix, and you'd expect `a.shape == (5, 5, 5, 5)` and `b.shape == (5,)` to do matrix-vector, but NumPy picks the opposite interpretations.

Comment: The `...` part is meant to be the same for both inputs. The behavior appears essentially undefined if broadcasting is needed to make the dimensions match.